# What is this closed door in the sewers?

Tags: a-wizards-lizard

So there's this brown door I encountered in the sewers.

[image: locked door]

At this moment I'm holding both the slime key from the golden chest and one of those golden keys obtainable from a merchant.
However, I can't open the door.

So what's the secret puzzle that I have to unriddle to open this thing?